# Relating Fatou's Lemma and Jensen's Inequality

Tags: integration, measure-theory, intuition, jensen-inequality

If there is a sense in which $\liminf$ is a "concave" function, then we would expect Fatou's Lemma as a consequence of Jensen's inequality: Is there any way to make this precise?

For a small example that shows I'm not entirely making this up, my intuition for $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ comes from the following picture (which is of one sequence of reals, but for functions we can imagine this picture happens pointwise):

[image: a depiction of limsup and liminf]

Notice the $\limsup$ line curves in a "convex" way, and the $\liminf$ line curves in a "concave" way. Then, informally, we would expect (by Jensen's inequality):

$$\limsup \int f_n \leq \int \limsup f_n$$

$$\int \liminf f_n \leq \liminf \int f_n$$

Of course, these both agree with the correct inequalities based on Fatou's lemma.

I've looked around MSE for related questions
(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117056/fatous-lemma-and-jensens-inequality) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242920/what-are-some-tricks-to-remember-fatous-lemma) for example, though the first link is more interesting) but I haven't found any anything that addresses this in a satisfying way.

Is there any way to make this intuition precise?

---

**Edit:**

To give more context for making sense of this, we might view
$\liminf$ as a function $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then we curry $f_n(x)$ in the opposite order to the usual way. That is, we view it as associating to each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ a function $f_{-}(x) : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Now Fatou's lemma exactly says that $\int \liminf \circ f_{-}(x) d\mu(x) \leq \liminf \int f_{-}(x) d\mu(x)$, where one of our integrals is $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ valued by defining $\left ( \int f_{-}(x) d\mu(x) \right )_n = \int f_{n}(x) d\mu(x)$.

I don't know if anyone has considered any machinery like this, if it is at all useful, etc. Which is why I'm asking this question

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would the downvoter kindly explain their issue with this question?

Comment: Concave function  of what? Jensen's inequality is for single function, not a sequence, Yout idea is too vague so I downvoted it.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy -- I've edited my question to show how this might be made to typecheck

Comment: if I remember correctly, Jensen's inequality is for a fixed function, while Fatou's lemma considers a kind of convergence for something that is almost a limit (limsup or liminf), how would the implication you say? did you try to test it?